# Нужно в python файле открыть другой python файл, с абсолютным путём заданным пользователем

Tags: python

У меня есть 2 файла:

prog.py(Допустим по пути C:\prog.py)

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

filepath = askopenfilename() # "D:/path/file.py"
file = open(filepath, "r")
```

и file.py

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print("test")
```

Как импортировать файл file.py, или если точнее класс `SomeClass` из file.py во время работы программы? без использования "import something.something_another"

Comment: Что значит ипортировать? в рантайме узнавая где лежит и подключить? Если да, то зачем открывать файл через open?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @vitidev, если можно без open, то как? Конечно я могу попробовать через exec сделать это, но вы понимаете, насколько это неудобно делать в пределах метода.

Comment: родной [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly) не подходит?

Comment: ``open()`` примерно так же связан с импортом модуля, как фотография яблока связана с настоящим яблоком. И там и там мы видим яблоко, но есть нюанс.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ обнаружил в стандартной библиотеке [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#checking-if-a-module-can-be-imported).

```
import importlib.util
import sys

# For illustrative purposes.
name = 'itertools'

if name in sys.modules:
    print(f"{name!r} already in sys.modules")
elif (spec := importlib.util.find_spec(name)) is not None:
    # If you chose to perform the actual import ...
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    sys.modules[name] = module
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    print(f"{name!r} has been imported")
else:
    print(f"can't find the {name!r} module")
```